# Spark-like methods for groupby in python

Tags: python

After using Spark for a while,  trying to use groupby() in plain Python seems unnecessary complicated

I use this code

```
([ (k,list(v)) 
   for k,v in itertools.groupby(
                                sorted(
                                       data
                                       ,key=itemgetter(0))
                                ,key=itemgetter(0))]
)
```

Without sorting the data first, it gives a wrong answer (considers the key to be in compact continuous regions).

I understand the point of providing an iterable, but it forces me to build explicitly a list every time.

I know I can simply go and plug this in a method, but is there a more compact and efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

The requirement that the input to `itertools.groupby` needs to be sorted doesn't surprise me given that is the only way to have an iterator-based solution to the groupby problem (i.e. you group as you go rather than having to visit all elements before returning anything).

If this is ugly/ inconvenient to you why not just wrap the function yourself?:

```
def mygroupby(iterable, key):
    return itertools.groupby(sorted(iterable, key=key), key=key)
```

Comment: I am not interested in having it on the fly, but a simple list of tuples as `[ ( key , [ (key , value) ] )]`. I know that I can define my own `groupby` and a dictionary would be more efficient, `mydict[key].append(key,value)` and then simply converting it to a list. I was curios if there is something I am missing

Comment: @RaduIonescu I believe that my understanding is consistent with yours- like you say from an efficiency point of view doesn't really make sense to use the itertools method unless your data is already presorted